# CMake File API "no reply dir found"

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, clion

I have trouble using toolchains in Docker from CLION. My Docker container is based on ubuntu 18.04 and CMake 3.17 is installed. The image definition is based on [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/clion-remote/blob/master/Dockerfile.remote-llvm-project-env) reference implementation.

When I reload the CMake project with CLion, the following error is shown.

```
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/tmp.vmmD6opEtD/cmake-build-debug-local-docker
CMake File API: /path/to/glow/cmake-build-debug-local-docker: no reply dir found
```

When I configure the CMake project in the Docker container directly, it succeeded. I believe there is nothing wrong with the CMake project itself.

What does "no reply dir found" mean? There is no clue for this error message even with googling.

Answer (score 2):

I have this error sometimes when CLion is using `rsync` to sync files. Disabling rsync gets rid of this error:

[image]

The problem is that the file sync is slower, but slow is better than non-functional :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error, in my case setting up SSH to avoid asking for passphrase, that is on a terminal run `ssh-add` then try to reload the CMake project

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem.
Your build dir in clion cmake project settings is other than the one appear in the cmake options specified there.

Comment: Im having this problem as well. But I do not understand how you solved the problem? 

My clion cmake project setting has the Build directory path set to: /some/path

This is the error:

Build files have been written to: /some/path
Cmake File API: /some/path: no reply dir found

Comment: Check if you have another build folder specified in the cmake flags

Comment: Just checked, I dont add another build folder in the cmake flags manually, I specify it in CLion under Build, Execution, Deployment -> CMake and then "Build directory". This directory then gets added as a "-B" flag when running the cmake. Any other Ideas?